# Ordinal Logistic Regression Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r

I am trying to use an ordinal logistic regression model that predicts length of stay (los) which I converted to an ordered factor using total payment amount (total_payment_amount) and insurance classification (payer_grouping). These variables come from the healthyR_data file that is part of the `healthyR.data` package in R. When I try to run the ordinal logistic regression using the `polr()` function, I receive the following error:

```
# Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x' 7. stop("infinite or  
# missing values in 'x'") 6. svd(X) 5. ginv(object$Hessian) 4. vcov.polr(object) 
# 3. vcov(object) 2. summary.polr(polr2) 1. summary(polr2)
```

```
install.packages("healthyverse")
library(healthyverse)
dput(healthyR_data)
```

I used the code below to convert the length_of_stay variable to an ordered factor and then do my analysis:

```
dataW <- data |> 
  filter(payer_grouping != "?") 

dataW$payer_grouping <- as.factor(dataW$payer_grouping)

data_new \<- Data_W |\>
mutate(los = case_when(
length_of_stay \< 50 \~ "\< 50",
between(length_of_stay, 50, 100) \~ "50 - 100",
length_of_stay \> 100 \~ "\> 100"
)) |\>
mutate(los = factor(los, ordered = TRUE))

polr2 <- polr(los ~ total_payment_amount + payer_grouping, data = data_new)

summary(polr2)
```

Comment: I'd start with the hint in the error message - do you have any "infinite or missing values" in your columns that are included in the model - e.g. - `NA`, `NaN`, `-Inf` or `Inf` values in `los`, `total_payment_amount` or `payer_grouping`? Try removing them and see if you get the same error, or try working with a small complete subset first just to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in "# Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'" (without the rest of the warnings). In my case, the problem seems to be due to very large values in some variables (e.g. annual income in dollars). It could be easily fixed by rescaling such variables (e.g. to annual income in 1000 dollars).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Interestingly, I came here with the same problem getting NA in the Hessian matrix, precisely because of annual income in dollars!  Rescaling fixed, great spot!